# MonetDB; !FATAL: BBPextend: trying to extend BAT pool beyond the limit (16384000)

Tags: monetdb

Our monetdbd instance throws the error "!FATAL: BBPextend: trying to extend BAT pool beyond the limit (16384000)" after restarting from a normal shutdown (monetdbd start farm works, monetdb start database fails with the given error).

The database contains less than 10 tables and each table has min. 3 fields and max. 22 fields.  The overall database size is about 16 GB and a table with 5 fields (3 ints, 1 bigint, 1 date) has 450mil. rows.

Has anyone an idea how to solve that problem without loosing the data?

## monetdbd --version

MonetDB Database Server v1.7 (Jan2014-SP1)

## Server details:

- Ubuntu 13.10 (GNU/Linux 3.11.0-19-generic x86_64)
- 12 Core CPU (hexacore + ht): Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU X 980  @ 3.33GHz
- 24 GB Ram
- 2x 120 GB SSD, Software-Raid 1, LVM

## Further details:

# wc BBP.dir: "240 10153 37679 BBP.dir"

Comment: The error says that there are too many columns. From your description, that seems unlikely. As @mkersten said, it would be great if you could add more details.

Comment: Hey, added server details in my request, see above.

Comment: A few simple checks first. Go to your dbfarm/database directory and execute: wc bat/BACKUP/BBP.dir. It should be a low number. The more complicated step is to compile the sources and obtain a stacktrace using gdb to get some hints on the whereabouts of this bug.

Comment: added the wc output, we'll try to compile the monetdb source asap with debug.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds strange. What OS and hardware platform?
Are you accidentally using a 32-bit Windows version?

Comment: Hey, added server details in my request, see above. It's an Ubuntu 13.10 64bit linu.